# Get files that have certain extension and contain certain words in their folder?

Tags: python

I want to make a code that finds files in the subfolders given a main folder  that has certain extension and contain some words in their subfolder's name. How can i do that?

For example get files where their folder has the words 'dis' in their name and get the files that have `shp` extension in them.

Here is what I tried:

Only the part with the name is not covered.

```
rootfolder= directory

shapelist = []
   for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
       for name in files:
           if name.endswith('.shp'):
               shapelist.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

The tree is like:

```
rootfolder\
    subfolders(including two that have the words diss)\
        files inside these
```

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method and [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

```
shapelist = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
       # check if 'dis' is in the name of the subfolder
       if 'dis' in os.path.split(path)[-1]:
           for name in files:
               if name.endswith('.shp'):
                   shapelist.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

but this is a better way using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

```
from glob import glob
shapelist = glob(rootfolder + '/**/*dis*/*.shp', recursive=True)
```

Comment: with the last one you  do all that is in the first?

Comment: How to constrain it to search only in a given rootfolder and not everywhere with glob?

Comment: I edited my post to show how to do it from a particular folder -- yes the 2nd method should have equivalent results to the first but run faster.

Comment: Since you provided this method too can you tell me how to search for the extension only with glob?

Comment: `glob(rootfolder + '/**/*.shp')`